# How to do CVS coparision across two systems

Tags: svn, cvs

Is there any way to compare files from CVS across two different systems?
Is this possible in SVN?

Comment: As in diff or as in compare histories?

Comment: In Diff only. Not required any history.

Comment: Ah.  You should be able to find a diff tool that doesn't depend on the versioning system.

Comment: I am already using WinMerge to do so. For this I have to take two files in WinMerge and do comparison. But I want if there is any option which directly compare file with current version from two different systems.

Answer (score 0):

For Subversion `diff URL1 URL2` (`svn help diff`, third type of usage)

Comment: Thanks for replay. There is no any option for CVS?

Comment: @user1041580 - I just not used CVS very long time and forgot all. You have to find CVS-guru